# String interpolation format not working within firestore update function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to pass my `type` prop into a string:

```js
 db.collection("users").doc(user).collection("theme").doc(user).update({
        `button.${type}`: e.target.value,
      });
```

However, the  `` `button.${type}`: e.target.value, `` renders the error `Unexpected token (86:8)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the proper way to pass a string key to access a variable in a object is as `obj[stringKey]`:

```
  { [button[type]]: e.target.value }
```

you only need to be sure that `button[type]` is not undefined, otherwhise your object will be `{ undefined: e.target.value }`

Answer (score 0):

Is {type} a string property? if it is, you can try remove the curly braces

```
db.collection("users").doc(user).collection("theme").doc(user).update({
        `button.$type`: e.target.value,
      });
```